# "now" is not defined when trying to update time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So I am doing a vue.js project and I am trying to have the time update every second. I have initialized the time in data(), then created a function which should update it, and then called the function in mounted() to refresh every second. Problem is that when I call updateTime() it keeps telling me that 'now' is not defined. Why is that?

```
    <script>
import { createDOMCompilerError } from "@vue/compiler-dom";

export default {
  data() {
    const now = new Date();
    const hours = now.getHours();
    const minutes = now.getMinutes();
    const seconds = now.getSeconds();

    return {
      now,
      hours,
      minutes,
      seconds,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateTime() {
      this.now = new Date();
      this.hours = now.getHours();
      this.minutes = now.getMinutes();
      this.seconds = now.getSeconds();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.updateTime();
    }, 1000);
  },
  unmounted() {
    clearInterval();
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It should be `this.now` instead of just `now` in updateTime method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this.now` when assigning to `this.hours` etc

```
this.now = new Date();
this.hours = this.now.getHours();
this.minutes = this.now.getMinutes();
this.seconds = this.now.getSeconds();
```

Also note that `clearInterval` requires an interval ID to be passed in, which will be returned when you run `setInterval`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval

Comment: Yes that seems to have fixed it! I will mark you as the correct answer in a bit since it does not let me know, thank you very much! 
Also if you could tell me then what is the intervalID in my case? I am a bit confused about that..

Comment: You need the interval ID when it's returned, e.g. `this.update_interval_id = setInterval...`, then use it again later on with `clearInterval(this.update_interval_id)`. This allows you to have more than one interval/timeout on a page without cancelling them all at the same time

Comment: There are some examples on the `setInterval` docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval